# Changing URL according to the pages - Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am new to Code Igniter and this project is hosted in Amazon AWS,
there was another guy developing before me. 
He set all the pages so that when links are clicked the pages are routed 
but the address bar stays always "www.mysite.com". I believe because of this when 
the page gets refreshed it always goes back to the index page

I wanted it to show at least for example,
"www.mysite.com/privacy-policy" just omitting the extension. I tried commenting "RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|system|js|uploads|css|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]" in the .HTACCESS file but it didnt' work.

Any help will appreciate
thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: If you're looking to undo an ajax based site you'll need to do a lot more than set the htaccess back to CI's default.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what he did. Sounds like lots of ugly Javascript to me. Try turning off Javascript and load the page. Whatever happens *might* give you a clue.

Comment: I did turn off the javascript, no changes! I dont think this is a javascript problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the base url of the site in the config.php file?And did you put the relevant controllers to the relevant links in the html page?And other thing is did you call base_url() function before the controllers of the html page?If not check by doing these changes.Your htaccess file is fine.But is that the complete file?Try to change it to this....

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: still nothing happens. I'm not sure what you mean by "call base_url() function before the controllers of the html page?" do you mean I have to add the base_url before the actual link? or in the controller script? Also, when I hover on a link it displays the ip address instead of the actual domain name. dont know if that's a part of the problem, but need to fix this as well in time.

Comment: one other thing I forgot to mention is that in the .HTTACCESS file before i changed, there was  only one line. "DENY ALL". I dont know if that should help to determine if there's another script or setting overriding it.